# ¿Cómo acceder mediante un bucle a un array de objetos que a su vez contienen otros objetos?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente objeto:

```
objeto = {
    coche: {
        ruedas: 4,
        volante: 1,
    },
    coche2: {
        ruedas: 6
    }
}
```

estoy intentando acceder a coche.ruedas mediante un bucle `for in`, pero no logro hacerlo, accedo a `coche` y `coche2` sin problema, pero a la hora de acceder adentro no logro hacerlo.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes. He editado tu pregunta para mejorar el formato (el objeto que pones no es un objeto válido en JavaScript) y también he corregido la redacción para mejorar errores en el texto. Intenta siempre aportar preguntas sin errores y lo mejor explicadas posibles, y también es bueno situar el código que has intentado. De esa manera tu respuesta tendrá más posibilidades de ser respondida. Un saludo y te reitero la bienvenida a SOes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que esta es una forma bastante mas simple que las otras dos propuestas

```js
let objeto = {
    coche: {
        ruedas: 4,
        volante: 1,
    },
    coche2: {
        ruedas: 6
    }
};

for(let item in objeto){
  console.log(`${item} tiene ${objeto[item].ruedas} ruedas`);
  if(objeto[item].volante){
    console.log(`${item} tiene ${objeto[item].volante} volante`);
  }else{
    console.log(`${item} no tiene volante`);
  }
}
```

Comment: El solo pidio acceder a las ruedas,
Agregado de todas formas 

Answer (score 4):

tambien puedes hacerlo asi y no necesitas realizar 2 for.

```js
    const objeto = {
      coche: {
        ruedas: 4,
        volante: 1,
      },
      coche2: {
        ruedas: 6
      }
    };
     
    Object.keys(objeto).forEach((key)=>{
      console.log('Objecto competo')
      console.log(objeto[key])
    
      console.log('Ruedas')
      console.log(objeto[key].ruedas)
    });
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es buena por ser bastante sencilla, sin embargo, considero que puedes mejorarla explicando el propósito de `Object.keys()` y el porqué puedes usar `forEach()` sobre el mismo. Así otros usuarios que no conozcan sobre estas funciones o métodos tendrán una idea general de su uso y tu código les servirá como ejemplo. Además considera colocar un enlace a la documentación. Es una sugerencia, tienes mi +1 igualmente. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Estás accediendo a las propiedades del objeto mediante un ciclo `for in`. Si creas otro ciclo anidado dentro de ese ciclo, puedes acceder a las propiedades de cada uno de los objetos hijos:

```js
var objeto = {
  coche: {
    ruedas: 4,
    volante: 1,
  },
  coche2: {
    ruedas: 6
  }
}

for (var coche in objeto) {
  console.log("Propiedades de " + coche + ":");
  for (var propiedad in objeto[coche]) {
      console.log("    " + propiedad + ": " + objeto[coche][propiedad]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, eso ya lo había hecho, lo que no lograba era recordar como acceder al valor para imprimirlo, pero en tu ejemplo al final aparece, así que gracias, aunque sea de rebote me has solucionado el error. ^ ^

Answer (score 2):

- Puedes usar `Object.entries()` para transformar el objeto en un vector.
- Luego, usando `for of` podemos iterar sobre cada uno de los elementos del vector.
- Por último, usamos `iterables[i]` para acceder a los elementos del arreglo. Con `i=1` se accede a los valores de ruedas y volantes.

Del último punto anterior tenemos:

```
for(iterables of iterable) {
  console.log(iterables[1])
}
```

Que produce un resultado como este:

```
[object Object] {
  ruedas: 4,
  volante: 1
}
[object Object] {
  ruedas: 6
}
```

Ahora nuestro código quedaría así:

```js
    var objeto = {
      coche: {
        ruedas: 4,
        volante: 1,
      },
      coche2: {
        ruedas: 6
      }
    }
    
    let iterable = Object.entries(objeto)
    
    
    for(iterables of iterable) {
      console.log("Las propiedades son: ")
      console.log(`El número de ruedas es: ${iterables[1].ruedas}`)
      console.log(`El número de volantes es: ${iterables[1].volante}`)
      console.log(`---------------------------------------`)
    }
```

Obteniendo un resultado como este:

```
"Las propiedades son: "
"El número de ruedas es: 4"
"El número de volantes es: 1"
"---------------------------------------"
"Las propiedades son: "
"El número de ruedas es: 6"
"El número de volantes es: undefined"
"---------------------------------------"
```

Podemos usar el operador ternario para validar el caso en que no existe la propiedad `volante` en uno de los objetos. De esta forma evitamos que se muestre como **undefined**:

```
`El número de volantes es: ${(iterables[1].volante) ? iterables[1].volante : 0}`
```

Ahora nuestro código queda así:

```js
    var objeto = {
      coche: {
        ruedas: 4,
        volante: 1,
      },
      coche2: {
        ruedas: 6
      }
    }
    
    let iterable = Object.entries(objeto)
    
    
    for(iterables of iterable) {
      console.log("Las propiedades son: ")
      console.log(`El número de ruedas es: ${iterables[1].ruedas}`)
      console.log(`El número de volantes es: ${(iterables[1].volante) ? iterables[1].volante : 0}`)
      console.log(`---------------------------------------`)
    }
```

Comment: Otra forma de asignar `0` cuando el campo es `undefined` sin usar el operador ternario sería: `\`El número de volantes es: ${(iterables[1].volante) || 0}\``.

Comment: Gracias por la observación, lo había pasado por alto totalmente @MauricioContreras